# Does the new definition imply continuity and vice versa?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ in metric spaces, and let $x^*\in X$, and $y^* = f(x^*)$, $f$ is continuous at $x^*$ iff $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $B_{\delta}(x^*) \subseteq f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(y^*))$.

Now if we have a new definition by alternating orders of the quantifiers: $f$ is continuous at   $x^*$ iff $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, $B_{\delta}(x^*) \subseteq f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(y^*))$.

Does continuity imply the new definition? And does the new definition imply continuity? If yes please provide an explanation, if not could someone give an explicit counterexample of $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$? Thanks.

Comment: Your new definition says that $f$ is constant on $B_{\delta}(x^{\ast})$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$. Does this mean  $f$ is a constant function by the new definition, so the new definition implies continuity but continuity does not imply my new definition?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at every point according to your new definition, then it is constant (on each connected component at least, but for $\mathbb{R}$ that is indeed globally constant). So yes, your definition implies traditional continuity, but not vice versa.